# Esper pattern with OR triggers twice

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I have an Esper statement like:

```
select ...
from pattern[(A -> timer:interval(100 msec)) or timer:interval(500 msec)]
```

Usually the statement triggers once or not at all, but sometimes the statement triggers twice. Is this a bug or the expected behavior? If it is the expected behavior, what should I change in my statement so that it would only every trigger at most once?

Note: I'm using version 4.3 of Esper.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend updating to a newer version. The version you have there is really old. If still having issues you can create an issue in Github and attach a test case.

Comment: Not able to update the version right now unfortunately. Any alternative advice on how I could modify the statement in such a way that would ensure it only triggers at most once?